# Norm of a function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\phi(x_{n})=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-2)^{1-n}x_{n}$,where $\phi:c_{0}\to\mathbb{R}$,where $c_{0}$ is the Set of the sequences whose Limit is 0. I was asked to find the Norm of $\phi$. By applying norms inequalities;i obtained that the Norm of $\phi\le 2$. I think that the Norm is 2 but I dont Know how to prove. Can you Please help me?

Comment: Have you already proven that $c_0^* = l^1$?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Answer (score 0):

Given that $\tau: c_0^* \to l^1: \phi \mapsto ( \phi(e_n))_n$ is an isometric isomorphism. Then we have
$$
\lVert \phi \rVert = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert (-2)^{1-n} \rvert,
$$which you should be able to calculate.